# Format mm:ss to hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, datetime, format

I have some cells in Excel like `mm:ss` and would like to change for `hh:mm:ss`.

My problem is when I make the change in format cell, it is changing the `mm` to `hh` and the `ss` to `mm`.

Comment: So you just want to convert e.g. 15:45 to 00:15:45 by prepend "00" ?

Comment: Are these cells formatted as mm:ss, or are they string values

Comment: @duDE: I guess 75:45 should be converted to 1:15:45.

Comment: yes @duDE... you're right... just convert 15:45 to 00:15:45...

Comment: Mark... they are string values

Comment: no @Jean... duDe is right

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention formatting, you might try:

```
"00:"hh:mm
```

and/or

```
"00:"@
```

Comment: It can't possibly be a string, because if so, changing the format would have no effect; yet the OP does see an effect. Hence not a string. Note that if it were a string, your `"00:"hh:mm` wouldn't work either.

Comment: It's infinitely more likely that he doesn't know what "string" means, than that his report of seeing aa:bb change to aa:bb:00 is a lie. It's not a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "11:23" in cell A1, then by default Excel will interpret this as "23 minutes past 11 o'clock", not 11 minutes and 23 seconds — and not as a string.

This code will convert it to 11 minutes and 23 seconds in cell B1 and format it as `00:11:23`:

```
Dim d As Date
d = Range("A1").Value
With Range("B1")
    .Value = TimeSerial(0, Hour(d), Minute(d))
    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

Can also do this using an Excel formula:

```
=TIME(0,HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1))
```

or

```
=(HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)/60)/60/24
```

then format as `"hh:mm:ss"`.

Comment: Have you tested this? ;)